# Uploading a batch file to be downloaded with html

Tags: javascript, html, batch-file, download, href

I created a simple batch file called "example.bat" that I would like to download through the HTML `<a href="" download>` attribute. This worked for downloading literally any other file, but when I set the url for the batch file, instead of downloading, it opened a new tab with the code written across the page.

`<a href="www.example.com/example.bat" target="_blank" download>
DOWNLOAD A VIRUS
</a>`

I expected my batch file to download onto my computer, but it instead opened the file's code in a new tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your HTML is actually lacking an `href` attribute, and your file URI is missing `file:`.  I'm surprised this is working at all for you.  Try this:

```
<a href="file:///C:/user/admin/desktop/virus.bat" download>
  DOWNLOAD A VIRUS
</a>
```

Now, on your actual problem... with Chrome the `download` attribute is ignored cross-origin, and seemingly on `file://` origins as well.  If you were to host this on an actual web server, it would be fine.  Without the web server, the best you can do is use a [data URI](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs):

```
<a href="data:application/bat;base64,QGVjaG8gb2ZmCkVDSE8gVGhpcyBpcyBhIHRlc3QgYmF0Y2ggZmlsZS4K" download="virus.bat">
  DOWNLOAD A VIRUS
</a>
```

Comment: I did add a `=`, and the url. But just to be clear, I didn't copy and past this from the original code, so the actual code didn't have those problems. Thanks for the advise with the data URI. It seems to be working now!

Answer (score -1):

Add the following line to your `.htaccess` file:

```
<Files "virus.bat">
ForceType application/octet-stream
Header set Content-Disposition attachment
</Files>
```

This will treat your file as an attachment.

You can find more information about forcing files to be downloaded instead of opened in the browser at https://help.dreamhost.com/hc/en-us/articles/216363147-How-can-I-force-a-file-to-be-downloaded-

Comment: This answer isn't relevant.  There is no web server used in the question.